# Enable Syntax Highlighting together with a new design

Tags: feature-request

Is it possible to enable syntax highlighting (which is actually works on the SO) and a new design at the same time? I think it would be very cool!

Comment: ... and please please add Apex & Visualforce to the list of languages so we don't have to cheat with forced highlighting as Java & XML respectively?

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly with both the question and above comment. Both of these festures would be immensely helpful.

Comment: I wonder if Jin should be asked in the other thread or at least asked if he could read this one and try to respond to it?

Comment: @crmprogdev Question that are marked as "feature-request" are for administration, not designer.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know who was to respond to them or address them. :)