# Known-Grammars Syntax Highlighting

Tags: feature-request

I would love to have JS, HTML and XML syntax highlighting.  Unlike Apex or Visualforce, there is a known grammar for those and they're working fine on other SE sites.

Is this an option?

Related to: [Can we enable Syntax Highlighting for Apex and Visualforce code blocks?](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21/can-we-enable-syntax-highlighting-for-apex-and-visualforce-code-blocks) and [Enable Syntax Highlighting together with a new design](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/746/enable-syntax-highlighting-together-with-a-new-design)