# Line numbers and Color highlight is not visible in Code Block

Tags: support, feature-request

[image: no color highlight and no line numbers]

Why I can not see line numbers?

Why I can see color highlighting on some posts but not all?

[image: Can see color highlight but not line numbers]

Answer (score 5):

Line numbers have never been a feature and, as far as I know, there is no plan to ever implement them.

As for syntax highlighting, it will only work correctly if you either:

1. Tag your post appropriately
2. Use explicit highlighting hints

See also:

- [Can we enable Syntax Highlighting for Apex and Visualforce code blocks?](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21/2995)
- [Known-Grammars Syntax Highlighting](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1908/2995)
- [Enable Syntax Highlighting together with a new design](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/q/746/2995)

Comment: Tags you mean that if a post has apex code then apex tag should be there? What are the explicit highlighting hints?

Comment: @rahulgawale Did you even look at the top link I added in the `See Also` section? It should give you a better idea. You might still have to fill in some gaps, but your response seems to me like you didn't visit any of the links.